# Does ssh key need to be named id_rsa?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have come across this problem a couple of times when creating build servers with keyed authentication.

I was wondering if anyone else has experience this. I have a couple of keys for my current user that may connect to different machines. Let say machine1 and machine2. I have pasted my public key into their respective authorized_keys file. The first one I have named the first key id_rsa and the second key bender.

When I try to connect to bender I get the following output with my verbose ssh connection

```
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/bozo/.ssh/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /home/bozo/.ssh/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/bozo/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

It only offers the id_rsa key, as you can see above. Is this correct? If so why? How do I get it to offer more keys? I know it is a problem I see intermittently, because I at home I have multiple keys without much trouble.

I would also appreciate a overview on how the pub and private keys interact with the client and server. I thought I had a pretty decent idea, but apparently I am missing something.

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

By default, SSH searches for `id_rsa`, `id_ecdsa`, `id_ecdsa_sk`, `id_ed25519`, `id_ed25519_sk`, and `id_dsa` files. The keys do not have to be named like this, you can name it `mykey` just as well, or even place it in a different directory. However, if you do either of those, then you need to explicitly reference the key in the ssh command like so:

```
ssh user@server -i /path/to/mykey
```

If a command does not accept `-i`, e.g. `sshfs`, use the `IdentityFile` option:

```
sshfs -o IdentityFile=/path/to/mykey user@host:/path/on/remote /mountpoint
```

### How It Works

When generating a key, you'll get two files: `id_rsa` (private key) and `id_rsa.pub` (public key). As their names suggest, the private key should be kept secret and the public key can be published to the public.

Public-key authentication works with a public and a private key. Both the client and the server have their own keys. When installing `openssh-server` the server public and private keys are generated automatically. For the client, you'll have to do that on your own.

When you (client) connect with a server, public keys are exchanged. You'll receive the servers one, and the server yours. The first time you receive the server public key, you'll be asked to accept it. If this public key changes over a time, you'll be warned because a possible MITM (Man in the middle) attack is going on, intercepting the traffic between the client and the server.

The server checks whether you are allowed to connect (defined in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) and if your public key is listed in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. Possible reasons why the public key is denied:

- `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:
- `AllowUsers` or `AllowGroups` is specified, but your server user is not listed in the groups or users list (default not defined, placing no restriction on the users or groups from logging in).
- `DenyUsers` or `DenyGroups` is specified and you're in the users or groups list.
- You're trying to login as root, but `PermitRootLogin` is set to `No` (default `yes`).
- `PubkeyAuthentication` is set to `No` (default `yes`).
- `AuthorizedKeysFile` is set to a different location, and the public keys are not added to that file (default `.ssh/authorized_keys`, relative to home dir)
- `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`: your public key is not added in this file (note that this file is read as root user)

### Using multiple keys

It's not uncommon to use multiple keys. Instead of running `ssh user@host -i /path/to/identity_file`, you can use a configuration file, `~/.ssh/config`.

Common settings are the `IdentityFile` (the keys) and port. The next configuration will check `~/.ssh/id_dsa` and `~/.ssh/bender` only when connecting with `ssh youruser@yourhost`:

```
Host yourhost
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bender
```

If you omit `Host yourhost`, the settings will apply to all SSH connections. Other options can also be specified for this host match, like `User youruser`, `Port 2222`, etc. This would allow you to connect with the shorthand `ssh yourhost` instead of `ssh -p 2222 youruser@yourhost -i ~/.ssh/id_dsa -i ~/.ssh/bender`.

Comment: why do I need to specify the key? the whole point is so I can ssh to the machine easier.

Comment: Wait, did you name your publickey "bender"? You should have two files named "id_rsa" and "id_rsa.pub". Do not rename the files to something else.

Comment: no i have two sets of keys ones beginning with "id_rsa" and others beginning with "bender" when i try to connect to machine using the bender keys it fail one looking at the other machines keys being "id_rsa" once I rename the bender keys to id_rsa I am able to connec to that machine. why does this happen and how do I avoid having to do that.

Comment: @dustyprogrammer: Added example to avoid `ssh user@host -i .ssh/bender` each time.

Comment: Can I use wildcards for the Host? Like `*.dept.myuni.org`?

Comment: And are wildcards on the `IdentityFile` allowed as well? E.g. for adding another directory with keys.

Comment: @StevenRoose from `ssh_config(5)`: *The file name may use the tilde syntax to refer to a user's home directory or one of the following escape characters: '%d' (local user's home directory), '%u' (local user name), '%l'  (local  host  name), '%h' (remote host name) or '%r' (remote user name).* It is not possible to specify wild cards, but this should be convenient enough I guess. Be aware that a server has to probe each key you sent, so specifying less keys is better. Wildcards on Host work, see again the manual page of `ssh_config(5)`.

Comment: My thinking is that you'd want a separate pair of key files for each machine you would connect to. That way, when you put the public key on the machine (that you want to connect to), it's easier to find and pick the file you need for this (they're not all in one file, id_rsa). Is my thinking correct?

Comment: @therobyouknow You do not have to create a unique key pair for every machine. Usually you have few keys, and append the public key of one of the keys to the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the remote machines. If you use the standard `.ssh/id_rsa` file name (or id_dsa, id_ecdsa or the recent id_ed25519), then ssh will try this automatically and you do not need to specify `IdentityFile` in your config (or the `-i path/to/id_file` parameter for `ssh`).

Comment: +1 thanks for answering my question, @Lekensteyn

Comment: Still a good answer but had some more thoughts @Lekensteyn - *only* curious, wanting to increase my understanding when you say "Usually you have few keys," - how do you decide on how many keys you should have? What I find puzzling is why the keys are stored in the same file - doesn't that make it harder for them to be 'separated' out and used for different purposes? Just my thinking, would welcome being enlightened. Thanks again!

Comment: @therobyouknow A host may accept multiple *public* keys for the same user account (likely owned by different people). Usually you only have a single *private* key that allows you to log in to such a host. If you have a different question, please ask a new one instead of commenting here.

Comment: I love answers that go beyond the required detail and take the time to explain the concept. Wonderful job! +1

Comment: how do I know what to set "yourhost" to? or is it literally setting as Host yourhost?

Comment: @landed It is the host of the SSH server (it could be an IP address or DNS name). I have tried to clarify that section, hopefully it helps.

Comment: Give this man a medal.

Comment: I think .ssh/identity is OK too.

Answer (score 53):

My favourite method allows the private key to be selected automatically

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/%l_%r@%h_id_rsa
```

SSH will replace %l with the local machine name, %r with the remote username, and %h with the remote host, thus if I wanted to connect from my machine called foo to bar as user, I run:

```
ssh bar
```

And ssh would automatically use:

```
~/.ssh/foo_user@bar_id_rsa
```

As the local host is also stored, this allows for home directories shared over NFS (different key per machine!) or even identifying which machine the key was meant to be on...

Answer (score 2):

In consideration of StevenRoose's comment that it takes longer to specify many keys, and I happen to be playing around with a lot of keys, I would like to suggest my personal solution.

I create a symlink to the key that I want to use at the time, and since that only changes infrequently depending on which project I'm working on, I am happy with it.

Here I have linked to my keys for machines running under virtualbox:

```
$ cd .ssh/
$ ln -s adam_vbox-id_rsa.pub id_rsa.pub
$ ln -s adam_vbox-id_rsa id_rsa

$ ls -l
total 12
-rw------- 1 adam adam 1675 2013-10-04 02:04 adam_vbox-id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 adam adam  396 2013-10-04 02:04 adam_vbox-id_rsa.pub
lrwxrwxrwx 1 adam adam   16 2013-10-04 02:17 id_rsa -> adam_vbox-id_rsa
lrwxrwxrwx 1 adam adam   20 2013-10-04 02:17 id_rsa.pub -> adam_vbox-id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 adam adam 3094 2013-10-04 02:09 known_hosts
```

One could also add a really quick script to change over to another set without having to manually type the **ln** command again.

Again, this isn't a solution for two keys only, but for a greater number, it might be workable.

Comment: I just add an alias in by bash_profile for each server I work with. So for a server called bob I just have this... alias bob="ssh bob.example.com -l pete -i /path/to/key" - then I just type bob - and I'm in!

Comment: While it's sometimes easier to "get things done the way you already know", there are easier approaches if you setup .ssh/configs keys and hosts. This comment is directed at both the comment poster and commenter @Peter-Bagnall